# Build android_tutorial_camera

Tags: ros, rosjava, android-gingerbread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to connect my android phone with ROS according to the following tutorial:

Run a ROS Android example project
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Tutorials/Run%20a%20ROS%20Android%20example%20project

More precisely I tried to put the android_tutorial_camera to my phone, but I get at the tutorial http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/building.html allways the error message that Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:updateProject'. A problem occurred starting command 'android'.

If I follow the tutorial I get lots of error in the android_gingerbread_mr1 witch is necassary for the android_tutorial_camera. Basically the errors happens because the import of com.google. ... can't be resolved by the compiler.

What can I do to fix this problem and the resolve this library?

I think it's the same problem from the following link:
http://answers.ros.org/question/33511/build-failed-when-build-the-android_core-in-rosjava/
But although I followed the instruction there I wasn't able to compile the tutorials.

Thanks for helping

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44745/build-android_tutorial_camera/) by [Marcel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3276/marcel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-09-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-28**:
Make sure you have a look at the [support site](http://ros.org/wiki/Support). Please always copy-paste the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer on the webpage http://www.dobots.nl/blog/-/blogs/android-and-rosjava

Adding the following lines to the ~/.bashrc file hepled:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools  # Depends on where you install Android Developer Tools
sudo killall java
```

---

Originally posted by [Marcel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3276/marcel/) with karma: 66 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2